# How to fix a distorted "File and Folder" view after upgrading to Mountain Lion and deletng Houdini?

Tags: finder, macos

When I had Lion, I used [Houdini](https://sites.google.com/site/elementninety3/houdini) to show hidden files and folders. But after I upgraded my OS to Mountain Lion, it seems like Houdini is not working correctly. So I deleted Houdini.

But now it seems like my files and folders in Finder are distorted *(see image below)*. I'm not sure if this because of Houdini or because of Mountain Lion bugs.

[image]

I already tried sort by name, it sorted at the moment. But when I reopened the same folder, the file back distorted.

How can I fix it?

Comment: [A related question at Super User](http://superuser.com/a/456362). You could try deleting all .DS_Store files and then setting sorting by name as the default in the view options.

Comment: @LauriRanta Already do it. but not working.

Answer (score 3):

The files are not "distorted"; they just are not arranged in rows. When you have the files in icon view, you can arrange them however you like.

If you want to have a particular window arranged by name, you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to bring up the inspector pane, then select the criteria you want to "sort by"

[image]

Comment: yes i mean not arranged. sorry for my bad english. Will try it soon. the effect usually back when i restart my mac or idle for some hours.

Comment: @GusDeCooL I'm not quibbling about your choice of words; my point is that you might not want your icons to look like that, but that isn't broken; it's just arranged in a way that's different than you'd like it to be.

Comment: No it is broken. before i upgrade to Mountain Lion. There is no problem like this.